# React position fixed issue

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So I have a component which is basically a custom button, with `position: fixed`, and I need it to render twice, one next to the other, but how can I achieve this if this component has `position: fixed` ? Basically, Is rendered twice in the same position.

Here is my code, where FloatingButton is the component with the issue above:

```
    return (
        <div className="details">
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12} md={12}>
                <Header {...headerProps} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid container className="inner-container" justifyContent="flex-end">
                
                    <Grid item>
                        {floatingButtonProps ? <FloatingButton {...floatingButtonProps} /> : null}
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item>
                        {floatingButtonProps ? <FloatingButton {...floatingButtonProps} /> : null}
                    </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        </div>
    );
```

and here is the CSS from the Button component:

```
    min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 32px;
    right: 32px;
    display: inline-flex;
    border-color: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: max-width 0.5s;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also pass the value for `right` in props to **FloatingButton**
like,

For first button `<FloatingButton right='32px'/>` and for second one `<FloatingButton right='132px'/>`
and in the Button component, you can assign it as CSS property

Answer (score 2):

`position:fixed`: An element with `position: fixed` is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled. SO technically your code is working just fine.

Now if you want to achieve two "fixed buttons" side by side. One of the ways is:-  you should make the `container` of the button to be `position:fixed` and render the button without a `fixed` position